# How to pass parameters to CosmosAsyncContainer

Tags: parameters, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the method queryItems from CosmosAsyncContainer, as shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.cosmosasynccontainer.queryitems?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-cosmos-cosmosasynccontainer-(t)queryitems(java-lang-string-com-azure-cosmos-models-cosmosqueryrequestoptions-java-lang-class(t))

So far I have been able to perform a query by concatenating the query String with a parameter, like

`String query = QUERY + "\"" + value + "\"";`

I would like to avoid this concatenation and pass the parameter in a different way. Maybe by changing the CosmosQueryRequestOptions,
for now I use them like this:
 `CosmosQueryRequestOptions queryOptions = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the query by using string concatenation, you can make use of [`SqlQuerySpec(String queryText, List<SqlParameter> parameters)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.models.sqlqueryspec.sqlqueryspec?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-cosmos-models-sqlqueryspec-sqlqueryspec(java-lang-string-com-azure-cosmos-models-sqlparameter-)) which lets you create a parameterized query.

Something like:

```
SqlQuerySpec spec = new SqlQuerySpec(
           "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = @id",
           new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter("@id", "id-value")));
```

You can then use the following override of the `queryItems` method: [`<T>queryItems(SqlQuerySpec querySpec, CosmosQueryRequestOptions options, Class<T> classType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.cosmosasynccontainer.queryitems?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-cosmos-cosmosasynccontainer-(t)queryitems(com-azure-cosmos-models-sqlqueryspec-com-azure-cosmos-models-cosmosqueryrequestoptions-java-lang-class(t))).

Comment: Using parametrized queries also benefits from query plan caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-java#use-query-plan-caching

Comment: Hello Gaurav, looks like my azure sdk does not have the SqlParameterCollection class. Is there an alternative?

Comment: What version of SDK are you using?

Comment: <azure-cosmos.version>4.25.0</azure-cosmos.version>
       <azure-core.version>1.25.0</azure-core.version>